# Add languages to Anki the text-to-speech?

Tags: amazon-kindle-fire, text-to-speech, ankidroid

On AnkiDroid, the only TTS language I can add is "English".  I'd like to have Chinese, Japanese, Korean, Spanish, and French, as well.  How can I get these languages to load up?

Answer (score 0):

**NOT WORKING.  The .mp3 files do not play on synced devices for some reason, even with a connection to the internet.**

The Kindle Fire HD 7 has no support for engines that support Asiatic languages.  So, you can either root the device and load in better engines, or:

1. Get on Anki Desktop.
2. Install the AwesomeTTS add-on.
3. Restart Anki, then open the browser.
4. Select the deck you want to add TTS to in the left-hand pane.
5. Hit ctrl-a to select all of the cards you want to add readings to.
6. Click "AwesomeTTS" in the drop-down menu.
7. Select "add readings" and then follow the dialog.